# Overloading static and non-static member function with constraint

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, c++20, c++-concepts

Is this code valid?

```
template<bool b>
struct s {
    void f() const {
    }
    static void f() requires b {
    }
};

void g() {
    s<true>().f();
}
```

clang says yes, but gcc says no

```
<source>: In function 'void g()':
<source>:10:20: error: call of overloaded 'f()' is ambiguous
   10 |         s<true>().f();
      |         ~~~~~~~~~~~^~
<source>:3:14: note: candidate: 'void s<b>::f() const [with bool b = true]'
    3 |         void f() const {
      |              ^
<source>:5:21: note: candidate: 'static void s<b>::f() requires  b [with bool b = true]'
    5 |         static void f() requires b {
      |                     ^
Compiler returned: 1
```

https://godbolt.org/z/f4Kb68aee

Comment: What about making the non-`static` member `void f() const requires(!b)`?

Comment: I'm fairly certain gcc is right and clang is wrong, but digging up an authoritative cite from the standard would be quite a bear.

Comment: @TedLyngmo, yes, I can do that, but it causes my total compilation time with clang to suffer significantly.

Comment: @DavidStone Oh, not good. Which overload does clang pick btw? Edit: I checked. It's the one with the constraint.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If we go through [[over.match.best.general]](https://eel.is/c++draft/over.match.best.general), we get:

> a viable function `F1` is defined to be a *better* function than another viable function `F2` if for all arguments `i`, `ICSi(F1)` is not a worse conversion sequence than `ICSi(F2)`, and then [...]

The only argument is the object argument, and we have earlier that:

> If `F` is a static member function, `ICS1(F)` is defined such that `ICS1(F)` is neither better nor worse than `ICS1(G)` for any function `G`, and, symmetrically, `ICS1(G)` is neither better nor worse than `ICS1(F)`; otherwise,

So the premise holds: all arguments for one function have a conversion sequence no worse than the conversion sequence for the other function. So we move on to our tiebreakers...

> - for some argument `j`, `ICSj(F1)` is a better conversion sequence than `ICSj(F2)`, or, if not that,

The only argument that we could have a better conversion sequence for is the object argument, and as established, that one is equivalent. So this tiebreaker does not apply.

> - the context is an initialization by user-defined conversion (see [dcl.init], [over.match.conv], and [over.match.ref]) and [...]

Nope.

> - the context is an initialization by conversion function for direct reference binding of a reference to function type, [...]

Nope.

> - `F1` is not a function template specialization and `F2` is a function template specialization, or, if not that,

Nope.

> - `F1` and `F2` are function template specializations, and the function template for `F1` is more specialized than the template for `F2` according to the partial ordering rules described in [temp.func.order], or, if not that,

Nope.

> - `F1` and `F2` are non-template functions with the same parameter-type-lists, and `F1` is more constrained than `F2` according to the partial ordering of constraints described in [temp.constr.order], or if not that,

Aha! In this example, we have non-template functions with the same parameter-type-lists (both are just empty). The static member function is constrained and the non-static member function is not constrained, which is the most trivial kind of "more constrained" (see [[temp.constr.order]](https://eel.is/c++draft/temp.constr.order)).

As such, I think that clang (and msvc) are correct to accept the program and gcc is incorrect to reject it. (submitted [103783](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=103783)).

Answer (score 1):

Your code is ill-formed according to C++20 standard [class.static.mfct#2](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/class.static.mfct#2):

> There shall not be a static and a non-static member function with the same name and the same parameter types ([over.load]).

There is no exception here for the presence of `requires`-clause to differentiate member functions, only same name and the same parameter types. And it is exactly our case: the same name is `f`, and the same parameter types is empty set.

So Clang and MSVC are wrong in accepting the code. But the diagnostics of GCC is definitely confusing.

With some minor tweaks in the code (removed `const` in not-static member function and get its address in the code), Clang and MSVC also show to have big problems with it:

```
template<bool b>
struct s {
    void f() {}
    static void f() requires b {}
};

int main() {
    s<true>().f();
    void (s<true>::*x)() = &s<true>::f;
}
```

Demo: https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/vdq9j63Gs

Comment: It looks like that wording was changed to a non-normative note and expanded in N4868 to say: "There cannot be a static and a non-static member function with the same name, parameter-type-list, and trailing requires-clause ([over.load]).". https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4868/class.static.mfct#2. Later versions of the standard removed the sentence entirely.

Comment: @DavidStone, thanks, I thought N4861 was the latest C++20 daft, and N4868 is already a C++23 draft: https://github.com/cplusplus/draft/releases/tag/n4868

Comment: Oh, good point. I misread "Pre-Fall 2020 C++ working draft" as "Pre-Fall C++20 working draft". However, given that it's supposed to contain only editorial changes, I suspect that this was just a bug fix of wording that wasn't updated for concepts?