# Static and non-static member function templates with the same parameter types and requires clause in C++

Tags: c++, static, language-lawyer, overloading, c++20

Static and non-static member functions with the same parameter types cannot be overloaded. But if member functions are templates and one of them has `requires` clause then all compilers allow it. But the problems appear when one calls *both* of the member functions:

```
struct A {
    static int f(auto) { return 1; }
    int f(auto) requires true { return 2; }
};

int main() {
    [[maybe_unused]] int (A::*y)(int) = &A::f; // ok everywhere (if no below line)
    [[maybe_unused]] int (*x)(int) = &A::f; //ok in GCC and Clang (if no above line)
}
```

If only one (any) line is left in `main()` then GCC and Clang accept the program. But when both lines in `main()` are present, Clang prints

```
error: definition with same mangled name '_ZN1A1fIiEEiT_' as another definition
```

and GCC reports an internal compiler error. Demo: https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/4c1z7fWvx

Are all compilers wrong in accepting `struct A` definition with overloaded static and not-static member functions? Or they just have similar bugs in the calling of both functions.

Comment: This is essentially a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70429541/overloading-static-and-non-static-member-function-with-constraint unless I'm missing something.

Comment: Thanks for the reference. In that question the answer is that Clang is correct, which GCC is not, while here both shows the same behavior.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is valid code as per [[over.over]p4](https://eel.is/c++draft/over.over#4) which says:

> Non-member functions, static member functions, and explicit object member functions match targets of function pointer type or reference to function type. Implicit object member functions match targets of pointer-to-member-function type.

The error that clang and gcc produce are mangling bugs see [clang bug: function signature constraints are not a part of mangled name](https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project/issues/49884) which was just fixed and [gcc bug: function signature constraints are not a part of mangled name](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=100825).

Answer (score 1):

This is quite messy! While skimming through the standard, I found this much simpler example in [[over.over]](https://eel.is/c++draft/over.over#6):

```
struct X {
  int f(int);
  static int f(long);
};

int (X::*p1)(int)  = &X::f;     // OK
int    (*p2)(int)  = &X::f;     // error: mismatch
int    (*p3)(long) = &X::f;     // OK
```

So I first tried the two valid lines, but even they are rejected (independently of each other) by all three compilers. That is a problem.

Looking further, about the address of function templates, [[temp.deduct.funcaddr]](https://eel.is/c++draft/temp.deduct.funcaddr#1) says:

> Template arguments can be deduced from the type specified when taking the address of an overload set.
> If there is a target, the function template's function type and the target type are used as the types of P and A, and the deduction is done as described in [temp.deduct.type].
> Otherwise, deduction is performed with empty sets of types P and A.

Such targets are described in [[over.over]](https://eel.is/c++draft/over.over#1), and in your example are of the first type:

> (1.1)
> an object or reference being initialized ([dcl.init], [dcl.init.ref], [dcl.init.list]),

Even before considering any constraints, it seems to me that a compiler should be able to identify a unique candidate in both of your cases, just as in the simpler examples, given that the targets have different signatures.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [latest draft of C++20 standard, class.static.mfct#2](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/class.static.mfct#2):

> There shall not be a static and a non-static member function with the same name and the same parameter types ([over.load]).

There is no exception here for the presence of `requires`-clause to differentiate member functions, only same name and the same parameter types. So the definition of `struct A` is malformed in C++20.

The same item was rephrased In the [first draft of C++23, class.static.mfct#2](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4868/class.static.mfct#2)

> There cannot be a static and a non-static member function with the same name, parameter-type-list, and **trailing requires-clause** ([over.load]).

According to this, the definition of `A` is already fine. And it looks like GCC, Clang, and MSVC all follow this statement even in C++20 mode. And the errors we observe happen because of same mangled names of both functions (which hardly can be fixed preserving the current ABI).

And in the [latest draft of C++, class.static.mfct#2](http://eel.is/c++draft/class.static.mfct#2) any restriction on having static and not-static member functions with same name and parameters are removed.